# Docker is getting killed itself after docker run

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile, angular7

I have written an angular 7 application and I want to deploy it on docker. I have created a Dockerfile in root folder. When I try to run docker, it gets killed by itself.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
# base image
FROM node:10.16.3

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@8.2.0

# add app
COPY . /app

# start app
CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

I am building docker by command

```
docker build -t example:dev .
```

To run docker I am using

```
docker run -v ${PWD}:/app -v /app/node_modules -p 4201:4200 --rm example:dev
```

Here is my output:

[image]

I am new to docker.

Comment: Please add the logs

Comment: have you tried to add to CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check

Comment: Now, I am getting error  **The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1** after docker build -t example:dev .

Answer (score 1):

I feel like your mistake lies in the volumes you define. You should not need to define any volumes on the docker run container.

Basically, you copy all components on your application in the container and start the container there. Then you, as you already did, specify the port the application should run and provide this outside the container to the host system.

TL;DR: Remove the '-v' arguments on the docker run command.

If you are new you can check out this blog post for guidance [medium](https://medium.com/@DenysVuika/your-angular-apps-as-docker-containers-471f570a7f2)